Noisy audio in Ubuntu 22.04
I am having bad audio problems since I installed Ubuntu 22.04. When playing audio or videos, I hear some noise or clicks like there was a volume saturation.
The problem affects both onboard audio and HDMI audio (both snd_hda_intel). I have already tried to change from Pulseaudio to Pipewire, to switch back to Pulseaudio, to disable power_save hda_intel option, to use tsched=0 option, change the sample rate to 48000, etc. Nothing worked.
My system is a P8-B75M Asus Motherboard with a Xeon 1270v3, and the HDMI comes from an RX550 videoboard.
I do not know much about Pulseaudio or Pipewire, so I cannot successfully debug files or check log files to track for a misconfiguration. I would appreciate if anyone could indicate me which files should I check.
Thanks for any help.
